# Bound for Outlyingness

Tags: statistics, inequality, self-learning, statistical-inference

Given a sample of $n$ data, $x_1, \dots, x_n$. Define the sample mean $$\bar x := \frac{1}{n}(x_1+\cdots+x_n),$$ and sample variance $$s^2 := \frac{1}{n-1} \sum_{i=1}^n (x_i-\bar x)^2.$$ To measure how far away an individual data is from the bulk, define $$t_i := \frac{x_i - \bar x}{s}.$$ ***The question is how to show that for all $j$*** $$\left|t_j\right| < \frac{n-1}{\sqrt{n}}.$$ It is sufficient to show that $$t_j^2 = \frac{(n-1)(x_j - \bar x)^2}{\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i-\bar x)^2} < \frac{(n-1)^2}{n}.$$ This reduced to $$n(x_j - \bar x)^2 < (n-1)\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i-\bar x)^2.$$ Then $$(x_j - \bar x)^2 < (n-1)\sum_{i\neq j}^n (x_i-\bar x)^2.$$ How to proceed from here, please? Thank you!

Comment: You must at least use $\le$ instead of $<,\;$ otherwise $x_1=0, x_2=2\;$ is a counter-example with $|t_1|=|t_2|=\frac{n-1}{\sqrt{n}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$

Comment: Also see https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/172461/how-to-prove-that-frac-leftx-i-barx-rights-leq-fracn-1-sqrtn/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have $\displaystyle \frac1n \sum_{j=1}^n t_j = 0$,  so $\displaystyle  \sum_{j=1}^n t_j = 0$ and $\displaystyle   \sum_{j\not =i} t_j = -t_i$, and thus  $\displaystyle  \sum_{j\not =i} t_j^2 \ge  \frac{t_i^2}{n-1}$.

You also have  $\displaystyle \frac1{n-1} \sum_{j=1}^n t_j^2 = 1$, so $\displaystyle  \sum_{j=1}^n t_j^2 = n-1$ and $\displaystyle  \sum_{j\not =i} t_j^2 = n-1-t_i^2$.

Putting these together gives $n-1-t_i^2 \ge \dfrac{t_i^2}{n-1}$ and so $|t_i| \le \dfrac{n-1}{\sqrt{n}}$.

If this had been a population with $\displaystyle s^2 := \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n (x_i-\bar x)^2$ then you would have $|t_i| \le {\sqrt{n-1}}$.

Comment: Thanks. But how to get "thus  $\displaystyle  \sum_{j\not =i} t_j^2 \ge  \frac{t_i^2}{n-1}$", please?

Comment: Also I do not know what you mean in the last line.

Comment: Try the [Cauchy–Schwarz inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality) where $\displaystyle \left(\sum_{j=1}^m x_j y_j \right)^2 \leq \sum_{i=1}^m x_i^2 \sum_{k=1}^m y_k^2$ where $m=n-1$, $x_j=1$ and $y_j=t_j$

Comment: The last line says that if you use the (slightly lower) population variance instead of the sample variance, then the bound on the standardised values $t_i$ is slightly looser

Comment: Do you mean replace $n-1$ by $n$, please? If so, I am afraid there is a typo in the last line.

Comment: Yes I did- thank you - now corrected