# What can be the upper bound of the deviatons in a data set, given the mean and the SD?

Tags: statistics, variance, standard-deviation, descriptive-statistics

Let $X$ be a set of $n$ numbers with the mean $m$ and the SD $\sigma$. Let the maximum deviation $$D=max\{|x-m|:x\in X\}$$. Then $$D^2/n\leq\sigma^2$$ so $$D\leq\sqrt{n}\sigma$$ is an upper bound of $D$. Equality doesn't hold for $n>1$, because $$\sum_{x\in X}(x-m)=0$$
and I would like to find a lesser upper bound, or ideally, the supremum for $D$ of $n$ numbers, say $D_n$. Clearly $D_1=0$ and for $x_1\leq x_2$ $$D_2=\frac{x_2-x_1}{2}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\sigma$$, which are the exact deviations.

For $n\geq3$, I have considered the bipartite set $$X=\{m+d,m-\frac{d}{n-1},m-\frac{d}{n-1},\dots\}$$ with $d>0$, for which $d=\sqrt{n-1}\sigma$. But I'm not sure if $$D_n\leq\sqrt{n-1}\sigma$$. Any suggestions or known facts?

Comment: This might look like a statistics question but it's practically more of an algebraic exercise so I decided to post it here.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3137170/show-that-max-1-leq-i-leq-nx-i-barx-fracn-1s-sqrtn

Comment: @d.k.o. Thank you for the insight. That does proves that my $D_n\leq\sqrt{n-1}\sigma$ and I have found that the inequality was first published by Samuelson(1968). Link: https://www.jstor.org/stable/2285901

Comment: I have also been informed about these excellent posts from before. So I'll close this question and leave the links here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1060537/bound-for-outlyingness https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/172461/how-to-prove-that-frac-leftx-i-barx-rights-leq-fracn-1-sqrtn